# how can i sort a 2d vector without change the original vector with insertion sort

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

hi i'm new to c++ and pointers so I just want ask
how to insertion sort a 2d string vector x without sorting it directly

at the end it should look like
`vector[vector[sorted],vector[sorted]........]`

requirement: (Do not sort the strings directly because it will result in too much data movement. To be eﬃcient, sort pointers to the strings instead.
) and the only lib i can use is iostream, vector and string

so i have to create of a 2d vector pointer point to the 2d vector then sort the pointer pos 
so I have tried to create a

```
vector<vector<string>> *p
```

to point to the 2d vector, but I can't find out a way that is other than `(*p)[i][j]` to access the vector 
but `(*p)[i][j]` will edit the original vector.

I have implemented it without using the pointers

the shiftstring comes from reading each line in a file and then doing cirual shift with each line,

```
vector<vector<string > > shiftstring;
for (int y = 0; y < shiftstring.size(); y++) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < shiftstring[y].size(); i++) 
    {
        string key = shiftstring[y][i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && shiftstring[y][j] > key) {
            shiftstring[y][j + 1] = shiftstring[y][j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        shiftstring[y][j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think pointers are needed? Do you have to use insertion sort? If not, this becomes trivial: `for (auto& vec : shiftstring) { std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end()); }`. Remember to `#include <algorithm>`. Or, if I have misunderstood you, could you clarify what do you mean by "*without changing x*"? By the way - *in place* or not has nothing to do with that. You can always make a copy of `x` and then apply the above solution.

Comment: ...and had we gotten more info I might even have been able to  propose`for_each(std::execution::par, ..`

Comment: @Fureeish  i have to use pointer and insertion sort it is the requirment, and i cant use algorithm lib the only lib i can use is vector string and iostream. so the question is that i cant modfity the shiftstring, i have to use pointer point to shiftstring then sort the pointers position. so when i cout the pointer's value it would look like sorted.

Comment: Why do you have to use a pointer? A pointer points to some data. It will not enable you to *view modified `x` without modifying `x`*. Please be more specific in your problem description.

Comment: @daydrak That is pretty important information. Edit your question. It starts looking like a school assignment.

Comment: Best way to sort without changing the source is to make a copy and sort the copy.

Comment: @Fureish that is the requirement : Do not sort the strings directly because it will result in too much data movement. To be eﬃcient, sort pointers to the strings instead.

Comment: "_it will result in too much data movement. To be eﬃcient, sort pointers to the strings instead_" - Eh? Why not trust the creators of the moved objects to have implemented move semantics efficiently?

Comment: Be glad you have skills to identify these kinds of problems. Whatever grade you get on this, or future, assignments - if it looks stupid, it probably is and deserves discussion at least. It's not much comfort when you're dealing with it - I KNOW - but just keep questioning dogmatic "truths" and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Thanks :D

Comment: What if - You use the standard library to do the sorting/shuffling (without pointers) and [benchmark](http://www.quick-bench.com) the result against your teachers hand optimized version?

Comment: ... and when I see this: "_the only lib i can use is iostream, vector and string_" - I get provoked. Nothing stops you from implementing your own quickstort, does it? It's a quick study and reasonably easy to implement. Your teacher may say that you "stole" the algorithm - and yes you did. Professor Sir Tony Hoare invented it in 1960. You read up on it, implemented it and ... yaay! It's quick (unless your data is spread out to destroy it).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo   just finish the pointer sort after work and did some test,  didn't notice any "efficiently" difference in compile time on a 10000 line text file. yea but i got take care my grade so i got do what she ask to do even it is so stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you just misplaced the pointer - you don't want a pointer to your 2D vector. You want a 2D vector of pointers to your strings, i.e.: `std::vector<std::vector<const std::string*>>`. I propose the following solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    // the original vector
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec {
            {"text", "some"},
            {"multiple", "in", "vectors"},
            {"to"},
            {"sorted", "be"}
    };

    // the view - vector of vectors of pointers to the strings
    std::vector<std::vector<const std::string*>> sorted_view{};

    // for each vector of strings inside the vector of vectors...
    for (const auto& v : vec) {
        // ...we create a vector of views...
        sorted_view.emplace_back();
        // ...and push_back a pointer to that string into our view-vector
        for (const auto& str : v) {
            sorted_view.back().push_back(&str);
        }
    }

    // for every view-vector...
    for (auto& view : sorted_view) {
        // ...sort the pointers of that vector according to what they point to
        std::sort(view.begin(), view.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
            return *lhs < *rhs;
        });
    }

    // print the view-vector
    for (const auto& v : sorted_view) {
        for (const auto ptr : v) {
            std::cout << *ptr << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Notice that I am using `std::sort` from `<algorithm>`. There you should implement your insertion sort instead of calling the standard algorithm. Since this is an assignment, I will not provide that part for you. Just remember - you are sorting pointers but comparing them in regard to what they point to.

The above code for the input shown, produces the following output:

```
some text
in multiple vectors
to
be sorted
```

which I believe is what you wanted - a view to sorted data of the separated inner vectors.

Comment: really appreciate for your help

Comment: @daydrak my pleasure. If the answer solved your issue, consider accepting it by clicking the tick just below its score. This will help future visitors of your question with similar problems to make sure that this indeed is the solution.

Comment: just did,, the light bulb came out my head after reading your first line. thanks a lot